# Can I submit a ios Build Which is developed using Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am developing a small 3D game using Unity free trial version ,

Can I submit this ios Build Which is developed using Unity free trial version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
check unity FAQ http://unity3d.com/unity/faq

> Can we sell games and make money with the free version of Unity?
>
> Yes you can create and sell a game with the free version of Unity,
>   without paying royalties or any revenue share. However, the free
>   version of Unity may not be licensed by a commercial entity with
>   annual gross revenues (based on fiscal year) in excess of US$100,000,
>   or by an educational, non-profit or government entity with an annual
>   budget of over US$100,000.
>
> Please also be aware that the feature set of the free version is not
>   intended for the production of professional games and interactive
>   content. Lastly, games made with our Pro trial licenses may not be
>   distributed nor used for commercial purposes.